# Tmux: How to move current pane to far Left/Right/Up/Down like in Vim

Tags: vim, tmux

In Vim, pressing `Ctrl-w` followed by `H`, `J`, `K`, or `L`, moves the current window to the far left/down/up/right, without messing up any of the other windows' ordering. I'd like to implement this same functionality with Tmux Panes, and bind them similarly to `Ctrl-b` + `H`, `J`, `K`, and `L`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try this](https://github.com/lacygoill/config/blob/f319cab041e07d44784b55c7c0e45c5b35d70628/.config/tmux/tmux.conf#L1177-L1181):

```
# move pane to the far right/left/bottom/top
bind H splitw -fhb \; swapp -t ! \; killp -t !
bind L splitw -fh  \; swapp -t ! \; killp -t !
bind J splitw -fv  \; swapp -t ! \; killp -t !
bind K splitw -fvb \; swapp -t ! \; killp -t !
```

Broken down:

```
bind H splitw -fhb \; swapp -t ! \; killp -t!
               │││    ├────────┘    ├───────┘
               │││    │             └ kill the previous pane
               │││    └ exchange the previous original pane with the current one
               ││└ the new pane should be created to the left of or above target-pane
               │└ full window height
               └ creates a new pane spanning the full window height (with -h)
                 or full window width (with -v), instead of splitting the active pane
```

For more info, see `man tmux(1)`:

- https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#split-window
- https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#swap-pane
- https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#kill-pane

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! Also, that's the longest `.tmux.conf` file I've ever seen!